# MS Word 2010 - Change Displayed Doc Properties in File>Info

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, documents, properties

When you click File > Info in Word 2010, you can view/edit the common properties for the document. I have added some custom properties like "Approver", "Date Completed", "Version" etc.

These are used for every document I/we use. Is it possible to change the properties that display in the File>Info page?

For eg I never use "Categories" or "Hyperlink Base", but would like to see the above custom ones listed there. It's annoying to have to go into advanced properties>custom etc, and most importantly - having to train staff to do the same, when half of the properties are available by just clicking "File"!

Many thanks

Comment: sounds like a good idea however it's probably not possible. I'm almost certain such behavior is programmed into the Word executable and cannot be customised.

Comment: There are ways to customize this but I believe you need to be using InfoPath to create a custom Doc Info Panel form and/or use it with Sharepoint. It may be worth checking out and testing an "Office 365" trial that has Sharepoint in it to see if it lets you customize the Doc properties and panels the way you want it and possibly justify the expense for a larger productivity gain. http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/p/53866/191821.aspx#191821